# How to use request.js in karma using RequireJS?

Tags: requirejs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write unit tests using Karma + Jasmine + RequireJS. When in my spec I use [request.js](https://github.com/mikeal/request) I get below error:

```
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Linux) ERROR
  Uncaught Error: Module name "lib/optional" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
  http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
  at /home/leo/workspace/Test-js/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:141
```

I have the following file structure:

```
-- app
   |-- node_modules
   |   `-- request
   |       `-- node_modules
   |       `-- requets.js
   |-- test
   |   `-- testSpec.js
   |-- karma.conf.js
   |-- test-main.js
```

Here's my **karma configuration**,

```
...
basePath: '',

    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],

    files: [
      {pattern: 'node_modules/request/**/**.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'test/**/*Spec.js', included: false},
      'test-main.js',
    ],
...
```

Also, here's my **test-main.js**,

```
...
baseUrl: '/base',

paths: {
    'request': 'node_modules/request/request',
},
...
```

And my **Jasmine spec**,

```
define(['request'], function(request) {
    describe("A suite", function() {
        it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```